# crystal report v8, vb6, command to print directly to printer without dialog box

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I use Crystal Report 8 in VB6. From within a form, I want to send command to CR to print directly to printer and without showing a dialog asking to specify the start and end page.

With newer version of CR, there is a command call `PrintToPrinter`. I couldn't find this command with CR 8.5

Can somebody here show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

set Report=crViewer.ReportSource
report.printOut false